# Create users with roles on client side with firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do my first login and authentication with firebase and I need three roles

Student, teacher, admin

My NavBar should render different things depends the role of the user signed in and I've seen that there is a way to use roles with firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

but if I'm not missunderstanding it, it should be done on the backend (I'm using spring)

I should know the role at every moment on client side How could I do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to check authenticated user custom claims in your web client code?

Comment: Yes, also if I can create custom claims on client code or I should do it always on server code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create custom claims on the client.  That would be a security hole, because users could just give themselves access to anything simply by modifying your code.  You need to [use the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on the server for that.

There is also documentation for [accessing custom claims on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client).  You use [getIdTokenResult()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdTokenResult) on the Firebase auth user object.  For example:

> ```
> firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
>   .then((idTokenResult) => {
>      // Confirm the user is an Admin.
>      if (!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
>        // Show admin UI.
>        showAdminUI();
>      } else {
>        // Show regular user UI.
>        showRegularUI();
>      }
>   })
>   .catch((error) => {
>     console.log(error);
>   });
> ```